# Problems with Android Development

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, galaxy

I wanted to get started in android development, so I bought a Samsung Galaxy Player to debug on.  Since then, I have only encountered problems.  Here's a quick rundown:

I am using the android plug-in with eclipse:

- code compiles, but the emulator doesn't run the code, it just does nothing
- eclipse doesn't recognize my android device

as far as my device goes:

- debugging is turned on, unknown sources on, etc.
- the adb shell doesn't recognize my device
- the google USB drivers i downloaded from the SDK will not work'
- When I try to load my .apk file, my device says, "Parsing Error"

I know this is a slurry of problems, but it comes down to one thing:  nothing works!  On the emulator or device.  I am extremely frustrated and I just want to see something work!  So any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

UPDATE: I got pretty much everything to work now, thanks to all those who helped!

Comment: So how we are supposed to help with all these questions lumped together.

Comment: Well help for individual problems is welcome - otherwise, I am looking for any simple mistakes that a beginner could make, things like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to get the Samsung OEM drivers:

http://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads

Here is a link on how to install them:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html#InstallingDriver

Answer (score 3):

Answer for issue 2&5 are: You need to downloaded Samsung galaxy drivers from samsung website, google usb driver won't work for samsung galaxy.

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse plug-in is wrapper around the Android SDK tools, so it may be more simple to first see if you can get these tools to work.

First, use the `android` program (in the tools directory of the SDK) to create a project:

```
android create project \
--target 1 \
--name MyAndroidApp \
--path ./MyAndroidAppProject \
--activity MyAndroidAppActivity \
--package com.example.myandroid
```

(Documentation : http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html.)

It generates a build.xml file that you can use to build and install your application with [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/).
Type `ant debug` to build your project.
Once the emulator is launched (it may take a few minutes), run `ant debug install` to install your application on the emulated device (you don't have to do anything else if you have only one emulator running).
You should now see your application the menu of the emulated device.

(Documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/building/building-cmdline.html.)

Comment: ok - there is no android.exe, just an android batch file.  Whenever I run it, it opens an empty DOS window and the SDK manager.

Comment: You need to pass the options. I'm not sure the `\` will work on Windows, so just type everything on one line. It should create a `MyAndroidAppProject` directory (or whatever you passed to the `--path` option).

Comment: Just type this line on the Windows command prompt: `android create project --target 1 --name MyAndroidApp --path ./MyAndroidAppProject --activity MyAndroidAppActivity --package com.example.myandroid`

Comment: ok - the project was created, it displayed a long list of files, but the "ant debug" did not work.